# Import Html not working on moneycontrol.com

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IMPORTHTML(" http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/futures/gainers/homebody.php?opttopic=&optinst=allfut&sel_mth=1&sort_order=0 ", "TABLE", 2)
```

I've tried using `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML` both, however, they do not seem to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is the error message that comes up on running both the queries:

Error Imported content is empty.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly do you need to import but LIST works from 1 up to 29

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/futures/gainers/homebody.php?opttopic=&optinst=allfut&sel_mth=1&sort_order=0";
 "LIST"; 29)
```

and also you can use "import all":

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/futures/gainers/homebody.php?opttopic=&optinst=allfut&sel_mth=1&sort_order=0"; 
 "//*")
```

Comment: Error
Import Internal Error.coming